# Custom User form instead of built in + custom required fields

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I was building a login/logout User system with django, and I started playing around with the django auth system.

I am using the custom Django UserCreationForm like so:

## views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/books/")
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, "registration/register.html", {
        'form': form,
    })
```

But this form renders a lot of unwanted stuff, as shown here: https://app.box.com/s/wmrtyal3mctb9hctsnom

First, I would like to get rid of the added information, is there a good way to do this? Are there any good ways to do this? Is there a way to edit the UserCreationForm myself or would I have to create my own form?

Second, lets assume I want to add more required fields to a registration page, what is the best way to do this? Say I wanted to make it the case that a person register male or female -I realize I should extend the user model, but how would I register both to the original user model and the extended user model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than extend the UserCreationForm class, you should rewrite it. Check out the source for it [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L66).

For example, if you wanted to get rid of the text next to the password field that says 'Enter the same password as above', remove this line:

```
help_text=_("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))
```

from django /django/contrib/auth/forms.py (in the link above)

---

**EDIT**: The reason I suggested that you rewrite the forms classes rather than extending them is because it is simply more convenient this way. From the Django docs:

> If you don’t want to use the built-in views, but want the convenience
>   of not having to write forms for this functionality, the
>   authentication system provides several built-in forms located in
>   django.contrib.auth.forms

If you were to extend your User model classes you would need to change the form classes accordingly. Again from the docs:

> As you may expect, built-in Django’s forms and views make certain
>   assumptions about the user model that they are working with.  If your
>   user model doesn’t follow the same assumptions, it may be necessary to
>   define a replacement form, and pass that form in as part of the
>   configuration of the auth views.

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#built-in-forms) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms) for more details

**If you simply want to change the UserCreationForm** you would edit the UserCreationForm class as in the forms.py module as I mentioned above.

**If, as you mentioned in your question, you want to add more required fields to a registration page,** you would need to make a custom User model. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) for details on how to do this

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how this is done? Do I plug in the source code and change it in my own forms.py file? If you don't feel likes explaining, could you point me in a good place to start rather than the source file itself.

Also why would I want to do this rather than just extending the model class? What are the benefits?

Comment: @ApathyBear updated my answer with more details. If this has answered your question please feel free to select it as the answer.